# Custom css - Wordpress Multisite

Tags: multisite, css

I'm using Worpdress 5.9.3 version.

When I try to make changes to the additional css on my Wordpress Multisite, I get an error message saying: "Something seems to be wrong. Wait two seconds then please try again."

I'm the super-admin of the multisite website. I also installed the Multisite Custom CSS plugin but it didn't fixed the issue.

I found the custom css style sheet in the database (in wp_posts)but I'm scared to edit it...

I read it could come from the "WP_optimizer" plugin but I don't have it, I only have "SiteGround Optimizer".

What are my other options? or what are the risks to edit directly the css from the database?

Thank you for your help

Comment: You'll probably need to contact the support teams for the Custom CSS and SiteGround Optimizer plugins for assistance with this.

Comment: Thank you Pat, I contacted the SG support team and indeed it was just the SiteGround Optimizer plugin causing the issue. I deactivated it temporarily and could save the changes to my additional css, then reactivated it!